# Opening ADODB Connection from Excel - Error 424

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

Am trying to create a generic function to return an open connection.
However, code bugs out at the last line when i set the function to the connection object. Need some directions to get this going. Thank you!

```
''
' Function to open an ADODB connection and return the connection object
' @param    strDBPath string containing full path to database of interest
' @param    strUserID optional string containing user name to use when establishing the connection (default: vbNullString)
' @param    strPassword optional string containing password to use when establishing the connection (default: vbNullString)
' @param    intOptionsEnum optional integer to open the connection synchronously (-1) (defualt) - 16 to open connection asynchronously
' @return   Object containing opened ADODB connection
' @remarks  Have only tested this on .mdb database (not .accdb)
Public Function vfnc_StartConnection( _
    strDBPath As String, _
    Optional strUserID As String = vbNullString, _
    Optional strPassword As String = vbNullString, _
    Optional intOptionsEnum As Integer = -1 _
    ) As Object

    Dim objConn As Object: Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
    Dim strDataSource As String: strDataSource = "Data Source=" & strDBPath & ";"
    '#If VB7 And Win64 Then
        strProvider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; "
    '#Else
        'strProvider = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; "
    '#End If
    Set vfnc_StartConnection = objConn.Open(strProvider & strDataSource, strUserID, strPassword, intOptionsEnum) 'Error occurs here
End Function
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: hey error is 424 object required! Thanks!

Comment: Hey all! Thanks for all the help! For completeness sake: both hstdggsdtgsdafssarf456 and YowE3K 's methods work (with the exception that i have to remove the parenthesis from Yow's reply), and I would personally use Yow's method just because it has 1 line less of codes...thanks for all the help!

Comment: I always forget that functions calls need brackets and calls to subroutines don't - I have corrected the code in my answer so future readers of the page don't have to read all the comments too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Open method of the Connection object does not return an object.  Therefore it isn't appropriate to set something to `objConn.Open`.

You would probably just want to return the opened objConn object itself, i.e.

```
    'Open the connection
    objConn.Open strProvider & strDataSource, strUserID, strPassword, intOptionsEnum

    'Now that the connection has been opened, return the connection to the calling routine
    Set vfnc_StartConnection = objConn
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your help! let me try your method with the one mentioned above!

Answer (score 3):

Here is my take on that, using ConnectionString properity, partially based on answer by YowE3K.

```
Public Function vfnc_StartConnection(strDBPath As String, Optional strUserID As String = "admin", Optional strPassword As String = vbNullString, Optional intOptionsEnum As Integer = -1) As ADODB.Connection

    Dim objConn As ADODB.Connection
    Set objConn = New ADODB.Connection

    Dim strDataSource As String
    Dim strprovider As String
    strDataSource = "Data Source=" & strDBPath & ";"
    strprovider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; "

    objConn.ConnectionString = strprovider & strDataSource & ";User ID=" & strUserID & ";Password=" & strPassword & ";"
    objConn.Open

    Set vfnc_StartConnection = objConn
End Function
```

Comment: hey hst! Thanks for helping with the code! May I just check if there's any difference between using the property and what Yow suggested? like in terms of robustness etc? sorry to bother!

Comment: There should be no difference between using Yow's suggestion and ADODB.Connection.ConnectionString properity. Its a preference - for me its easier to read.As far as robustness goes, im not aware of any differeces,  maybe someone with more experience wil correct me.